# Custom error handling CallAdapter for Retofit2 + RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Server sends response in case of success (code 2xx):

```
{
    "user":"User",
    "age":16
}
```

And in case of fail (4xx) the following Json **is sent inside `errorBody`**:

```
{
    "errorMessage":"Server is not working",
    "action":{
         ...
    }
}
```

I am using Retrofit v2.4.0 and RxJava2.

**How can I create custom `CallAdapter` for my case?** I have read Square's [ErrorHandlingAdapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java) but it was without RxJava2

Answer (score 0):

it is highly recommended using same object because of enque of retrofit, you can do this using generic model

```
public class GenericResponseModel {
    public int statusCode;
    public String message;
    public Object data;
}
```

and then parse into a particular model in your onNetworkSuccess and onNetworkError something like this:

```
HomeModel homeModel = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(genericResponseModel.data), HomeModel[].class);
```

using this approach you can make BaseModel and can treat with different responses too. I hope this is the answer that you are finding.

> you can remove statusCode,  message if no in response